# How can I Consume Key Events only on a Keyboard with a Specific HID in Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, keyboard, hid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OSX HID Filter for Secondary Keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676135/osx-hid-filter-for-secondary-keyboard)

I would like to write a Mac OSX Application that captures keyboard events on a second keyboard and consume them before other apps get notified? I don't my app to be notified of a keystroke on the main computer keyboard, just the second one. And I don't want other apps to get the keystroke, I want to consume it. Anyone here know the best way to go about this?

Comment: @GaretJax Your answer from my other question solved my problem perfectly. Here's the link for the benefit of others here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676135/osx-hid-filter-for-secondary-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

You will need IOKit to do this. The code would involve writing a kext and intercepting keyboard events and choosing whether to pass them on to the user space. Writing the entire approach here would be too complex and big but I can suggest a few references.

The code at [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) has quite a bit of low level code for device reading and interception.

Here is the custom kext that the author has written: https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/tree/master/src/core/kext

I suggest you look into the code to see how he has intercepted the keys, remapped them according to the user configuration and send them to the user space.

Comment: You're mostly right, but as I've found out in the meantime, you can avoid writing a kext and use the userspace HID library alongside with kIOHIDOptionsTypeSeizeDevice to get exclusive access to the selected device

Comment: I do recall trying out the `HID LED test tool` example from Apple Documentation which uses the user space HID Manager (on OSX 10.8) and I have not got it working properly yet. Out of the box, the application just crashes. It seems the example was built for Leopard and hasn't been updated since. I haven't located any latest examples yet.