# How to tap/hook keyboard events in OSX and record which keyboard fires each event

Tags: macos, hook, keyboard-events, tap, iokit

I've now discovered how to hook/tap keyboard events on OS X at a low level: [How to tap (hook) F7 through F12 and Power/Eject on a MacBook keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30372852/how-to-tap-hook-f7-through-f12-and-power-eject-on-a-macbook-keyboard)

Printing out the code from that answer:

```
// compile and run from the commandline with:
//    clang  -framework coreFoundation  -framework IOKit  ./HID.c  -o hid
//    sudo ./hid

// This code works with the IOHID library to get notified of keys.
//   Still haven't figured out how to truly intercept with
//   substitution.

#include <IOKit/hid/IOHIDValue.h>
#include <IOKit/hid/IOHIDManager.h>

void myHIDKeyboardCallback( void* context,  IOReturn result,  void* sender,  IOHIDValueRef value )
{
    IOHIDElementRef elem = IOHIDValueGetElement( value );

    if (IOHIDElementGetUsagePage(elem) != 0x07)
        return;

    uint32_t scancode = IOHIDElementGetUsage( elem );

    if (scancode < 4 || scancode > 231)
        return;

    long pressed = IOHIDValueGetIntegerValue( value );

    printf( "scancode: %d, pressed: %ld\n", scancode, pressed );
}


CFMutableDictionaryRef myCreateDeviceMatchingDictionary( UInt32 usagePage,  UInt32 usage )
{
    CFMutableDictionaryRef dict = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(
                                                            kCFAllocatorDefault, 0
                                                        , & kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks
                                                        , & kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks );
    if ( ! dict )
        return NULL;

    CFNumberRef pageNumberRef = CFNumberCreate( kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberIntType, & usagePage );
    if ( ! pageNumberRef ) {
        CFRelease( dict );
        return NULL;
    }

    CFDictionarySetValue( dict, CFSTR(kIOHIDDeviceUsagePageKey), pageNumberRef );
    CFRelease( pageNumberRef );

    CFNumberRef usageNumberRef = CFNumberCreate( kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberIntType, & usage );

    if ( ! usageNumberRef ) {
        CFRelease( dict );
        return NULL;
    }

    CFDictionarySetValue( dict, CFSTR(kIOHIDDeviceUsageKey), usageNumberRef );
    CFRelease( usageNumberRef );

    return dict;
}


int main(void)
{
    IOHIDManagerRef hidManager = IOHIDManagerCreate( kCFAllocatorDefault, kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone );

    CFArrayRef matches;
    {
        CFMutableDictionaryRef keyboard = myCreateDeviceMatchingDictionary( 0x01, 6 );
        CFMutableDictionaryRef keypad   = myCreateDeviceMatchingDictionary( 0x01, 7 );

        CFMutableDictionaryRef matchesList[] = { keyboard, keypad };

        matches = CFArrayCreate( kCFAllocatorDefault, (const void **)matchesList, 2, NULL );
    }

    IOHIDManagerSetDeviceMatchingMultiple( hidManager, matches );

    IOHIDManagerRegisterInputValueCallback( hidManager, myHIDKeyboardCallback, NULL );

    IOHIDManagerScheduleWithRunLoop( hidManager, CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode );

    IOHIDManagerOpen( hidManager, kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone );

    CFRunLoopRun(); // spins
}
```

How can I (maybe adapt that code to) identify which keyboard is responsible for a particular event?

The use case is  that I am planning to use an external keyboard which will be remapped,  but  at the same time retaining the original mapping for my inbuilt MacBook keyboard.

EDIT:
**[OSX HID Filter for Secondary Keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676135/osx-hid-filter-for-secondary-keyboard)**
https://github.com/candera/khordr/blob/master/src/c/keygrab/hid-scratch.c
http://ianjoker.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Joker/Joker/hid_test.cpp
http://www.cplusplusdevelop.com/72_17345226/
**http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/229902-which-keyboard-barcode-scanner-did-the-event-come-from.html**

Answer (score 2):

I was working on this problem, and finally got the solution. OP's code is correct, if you'd like the product ID of the keyboard/pad, add lines to the `myHIDKeyboardCallback()` function:

```
void myHIDKeyboardCallback(void* context,  IOReturn result,  void* sender,  IOHIDValueRef value){

    IOHIDElementRef elem = IOHIDValueGetElement(value);
    if (IOHIDElementGetUsagePage(elem) != 0x07)
        return;

    IOHIDDeviceRef device = sender;
    int32_t pid = 1;
    CFNumberGetValue(IOHIDDeviceGetProperty(device, CFSTR("idProduct")), kCFNumberSInt32Type, &pid);

    uint32_t scancode = IOHIDElementGetUsage(elem);

    if (scancode < 4 || scancode > 231)
        return;

    long pressed = IOHIDValueGetIntegerValue(value);

    printf("scancode: %d, pressed: %ld, keyboardId=%d\n", scancode, pressed, pid);
}
```

As @pmdj said you can use `IOHIDDeviceRegisterInputValueCallback()`, I was having trouble with this, and found that `sender` argument provided keyboard product id anyways.

Answer (score 1):

If you register the callback on each device of interest individually with `IOHIDDeviceRegisterInputValueCallback` then the `sender` argument will be a `IOHIDDeviceRef` indicating the device. (instead of using `IOHIDManagerRegisterInputValueCallback` where the sender will be the HID manager reference)

The only downside for this is that you'll need to register for and handle notification of hotplugging events for matching devices. (register whenever a new device appears, and deregister when a device disappears)

You can get HID device references using `IOHIDDeviceCreate()` - this takes an `io_service_t` as an argument. This in turn means you need to use the standard IOKit IOService matching functions to obtain and watch your list of devices, but you do indeed get an explicit list of individual devices, which you can query for names to show to the user, etc. The key function for this is [IOServiceAddMatchingNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IOKit/Reference/IOKitLib_header_reference/#//apple_ref/c/func/IOServiceAddMatchingNotification).

Comment: Thanks for picking up.  I should have thought of logging `sender`.  Just tried it with my code example, and it does indeed give a different value depending on which keyboard I'm using (1800442080 inbuilt, 1800440000 wireless).  Can I enumerate my keyboards in such a way that I can get the associated ID for the inbuilt keyboard?

Comment: Note that you're using `IOHIDManagerRegisterInputValueCallback`, whereas I'm suggesting [`IOHIDDeviceRegisterInputValueCallback`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IOKit/Reference/IOHIDDevice_iokit_header_reference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/IOHIDDeviceCopyMatchingElements) - subtle but important difference. I'll update the answer with some more details on HID device enumeration.

Comment: You say that with my current (`IOHIDManagerRegisterInputValueCallback`) set up that `sender`  will be the HID manager reference. But it actually report differently for each keyboard, which seems to suggest otherwise, as there is only one manager. This makes me wonder if it is really necessary to set the callback for a particular device.

Comment: Strange. The documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/HID/new_api_10_5/tn2187.html indicates that the sender should be the HID manager in this case. I guess cast it and try to do something useful with it, and see what happens…

Comment: Yes there is a contradiction between the documentation and the actual behaviour! I'm hoping the documentation is in error, because it's far more useful to receive the deviceID responsible for the event.  The HID Manager could probably be passed through using the `inContext` parameter.